# How to select/lock cell network frequency band?

Tags: android, gsm, lte

I am developing a very specialized piece of software for Android and I need the capability to select and lock on to a specific frequency band within the cell network. Does anyone know a way of doing this. I realize there is no API, but maybe by issuing AT commands directly to the modem chip or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the frequency using USSD codes, which you should be able to do programatically on Android (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22044551/334402), but I don't think any Api exists in standard Android to allow you actually select a particular frequency.

The operators would probably not be keen on this as it might interfere with their radio optimisation and planning if users started surfing for the 'best' (least busy, least power use etc) connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this almost impossible in End-User phones and software versions.

This kind of setting is possible and it is accessible via hidden menus. However, this kind of access is blocked in end-user software version.

Those menus and settings are accessible during development phase of mobile phones.

Of course, maybe you can set this setting or chance modem settins in a specific model.. But usually, this setting is blocked.

I don't think you can set it via applications as well. This kind of API/function is not exposed.