# I want to write Number sign in string of android

Tags: android, string, android-intent

hi guys i am making an app in which when user click on button it will redirect them to phone app of android with *700# entered. but the problem is when i write # in string it doesn't appear in phone app of android.

here is the code:

```
public void activite (View view) {
        String number = "*700#";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

it works fine except that number sign doesn't come up please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't appear in phone app of android."? Can you give a screen shot and tell us what you expect instead?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19168199/5471104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
public void activite (View view) {
    String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#"); //encode hash here
    String number = "*700";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number+encodedHash)); //updated here
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this method,

```
private Uri getCallString(String ussd) {

    String uriString = "";

    if(!ussd.startsWith("tel:"))
        uriString += "tel:";

    for(char c : ussd.toCharArray()) {

        if(c == '#')
            uriString += Uri.encode("#");
        else
            uriString += c;
    }

    return Uri.parse(uriString);
}
```

To call it,

```
String number = "*700#";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, getCallString(number));
startActivity(intent);
```

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22044551).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void activite (View view) {
        String number = "*700";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode( number + "#")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

this is how it works for me. THANK YOU GUYS FOR REPLYING MY QUERY!