# How to use a mobile provider's UUSD code service via an automated process?

Tags: ussd

If I have a SIM card from a mobile operator - for example, Vodacom in South Africa, I can use their USSD services via dialling `*111#`. Then I can navigate the options via using my mobile phone keyboard.

I would like to create a script that does this in an automated way. Is there a way to do this?

I see this is possible on an Android application ([Make USSD call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317981/make-ussd-call-in-android)). Is there a way to consume a specific mobile operator's UUSD service without first purchasing a SIM card from that operator? (i.e. running this from a server over http/tcp).

Comment: Hi How did you implement this Zach I would want to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the USSD menu you need to be on the mobile network. USSD is not internet, nor even data network. USSD is transported on mobile signaling network. Thus you need to have a SIM.

To navigate on a USSD menu via scripts, you may need few steps.

- You need a GSM device connected to your computer. A USB Modem is OK but all modems don't have this functionality. I have been using a Huawei 180E model.
- You'll need to talk to your modem over a serial line. On Linux, USB Modems can be reached as `tty` devices, typically on `/dev/ttyUSB0` (there is no absolute rule: some models only define 2 devices, some models define 4). For tests, you can use some terminal software. I use `miniterm.py`, a Python program, but `minicom` is OK as probably many others. For automation you may need a serial library for your preferred language. On the command line, there is `atinout` but I didn't manage to make it work properly, `socat - /dev/ttyUSB0` should also work.
- Finally, to talk to your modem, you need to use the `Hayes Modem AT` commands. You can read the `AT` command reference  [3GPP 27.007][1], chapter 7.15 for a formal documentation, but basically, sent to the modem (without the `#...` part):

  ```
  ATZ                     # to reset the modem
  AT+CUST=2               # to close any ongoing USSD session
  AT+CUSD=1,"#111#",15    # to initiate the navigation
  ```

  and if you get the menu, you're fine; if not, well, things are not desperate, but it may be more difficult as you'll probably need to play with character encoding.

  [1]: https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/10.03.00_60 (/ts_127007v100300p.pdf

Comment: Thanks - I suspected that via a SIM card is the only way

Comment: I am able to send AT commands to my Samsung Galaxy Note 8 through Putty. When you install Samsung drivers, it will also install a serial interface that you can connect to. For this to work though, USB debugging must be turned on. All the USSD responses will also show up on the phone, for security reasons. But to interact on the phone you need to root the phone and access the modem at `/dev/smdX`.