# How to press dialPad btn programmatically?

Tags: android, incoming-call

I am using Android Oreo and I need to press (or simulate if possible) some symbol on dialPad programmatically when pickedUp incoming call.

I have next code, which is pickUp phone call automatically:

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            if(intent == null || intent.extras == null)
                return

            val stateStr = intent.extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            if(stateStr == null || stateStr != TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
                return

            val savedPhone = prefs.getPhoneNumber()
            val number = intent.extras!!.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

            if (savedPhone != number)
                return

            val telecomManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
            telecomManager.acceptRingingCall()
        }
```

How can i press dialPad btn or simulate it programmatically?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to press the dial pad programmatically, as if it was possible, you could enter and execute USSD queries, which could for example transfer money from user's account.

Comment: you can easily execute USSD queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317981/make-ussd-call-in-android/33185775

Comment: that won't execute USSD query, it only will open the dealer with pre-filled phone number

Comment: ha-ha :)
If your app has "call_phone"permission - it will be executed ;-)
just tried!

Comment: ok, looks like that, but still - you can't simulate clicks on other app (without root rights)

Comment: sometimes you can: send intent for example can simulate some actions for some apps. and I am looking exactly for such kind of suggestion. or any other type of simulate: right now I found *telecomManager.sendMmi()* but it needed system permission